# In browsers videos start with black in them, once I reset the video they play as normal.

Tags: windows, google-chrome, video, flash-player

I've had this problem for a very long time. But I remember a day when it wasn't so.

**Starts**

[image]

**After going back to the start of the video**

[image]

I am using Chrome `Version 53.0.2785.116 m (64-bit)` on `Windows 10` with all the latest updates.

Maybe there is a way I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Does the same thing occur with a different browser?  Does the same thing happen with different video sites?  If you right click on the video, does the popup menu indicate that it's a Flash video?

Some suggestions:

1. Make sure your drivers are up to date, especially your video driver.
2. Check to see whether your has a BIOS update available.